# CCA security of a system that splits messages and encrypts each packet

Tags: aes, symmetric, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Propose a symmetric key based crypto-system for implementing a secure email system. This system is based on AES and CCA secure.

Suppose that you have to encrypt a large message and that this message is split 
in several small packets and the crypto-system I mentioned before is used to encrypt each one of the packets before transmission. Suppose the packets have different lengths. Is this system still CCA secure?

Comment: Secure against what?

Comment: @StephenTouset is it cca secure? or is there any case you think you can steal the message?

Comment: Is this homework? It appears to be phrased as such. If so, let me just give a hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_%28cryptography%29